# HTML converted to jQuery collection not searchable with selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to dynamically load a page using `$.get()`, parse the return with `var $content = $(data)`, and ultimately use selectors to find only certain parts of the document. Only I cannot figure out why the jQuery collection returned from `$(data)` does not find some very basic selectors.

I set up a [jsFiddle to illustrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jimp/mqaT7/) using a very small string of HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>See Our Events</title>
</head>
<body><div id="content">testing</div></body>
</html>
```

I want to find the `<title>` node.

```
var content = "<html>\n"+
"<head>\n"+
"  <title>See Our Events</title>\n"+
"</head>\n"+
"<body><div id=\"content\">testing</div></body>\n"+
"</html>";
var $content = $(content);
console.log($content.find('title').length); // Logs 0. Why?
console.log($content.html());               // Logs null. Why?
```

If I wrap a `<div>` around the HTML, then the selector works. (But if you look at the jsFiddle, other variations of the selector still do not work!)

```
var content = "<div><html>\n"+
"<head>\n"+
"  <title>See Our Events</title>\n"+
"</head>\n"+
"<body><div id=\"content\">testing</div></body>\n"+
"</html></div>";
var $content = $(content);
console.log($content.find('title').length); // Logs 1.
console.log($content.html());               // Logs subset of the source. Why?
```

Please look at the jsFiddle, too. It contains more examples than my code here to keep the post easier to read.

Why does my otherwise very basic selector not return the `title` node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) you will see some explanation concerning creating new elements with `$()` function. There is one particular paragraph which sheds some light on the issue here:

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

It looks like you may not be able to correctly create some basic elements. Above the quoted paragraph you can read about how the string is parsed and created.

I was able to create nodes on Chrome 22 with the following way:

```
var node = document.createElement('html');
node.innerHTML = "<head><title>Test me</title></head><body><div><p>Test 2</p></div></body>"
```

That created entire DOM node and puting this to jQuery constructor allowed me to build valid jQuery object, so:

```
var nodeElem = $(node);
nodeElem.find('title'); //get 1 result
```

This was done on Chrome 22 but the result may vary depending on the browser.

Comment: I was testing in Chrome 21. -- And thank you! Your solution worked. IE9 threw an error about not allowing `.innerHTML` to be called on the "html" node, but changing it to a "div" resolved that. I better test other browsers to make sure that `<title>` doesn't get removed... Oddly, the code is now identical to what jQuery claims it would be doing (but it doesn't work): "In most cases, jQuery creates a new <div> element and sets the innerHTML property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in." Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Loos like this is the culprit

```
var $content = $(html);
```

You are storing the string in #content

Whereas you need to do

```
var $content = $('html');
```

Comment: But I thought `$('string of HTML')` will return a set of Element nodes, not a single text node. Not true?

Comment: By doing $(html)  you are placing the whole object in a selector.. You need to store the $('html') // html tag selector   of the page coz you are searching for elements within it

Comment: But I want the entire string passed to the $() function so it will parse the HTML into a node set. I'm not trying to select the "html" node. I have updated the question for clarity by changing `$(html)` to `$(content)`.